# Java high performance linear algebra library with features similar to Scala's Breeze

Tags: java, performance, linear-algebra

I am looking for a library that would handle the addition of small matrices efficiently (with the lowest memory footprint). There are choices like JBLAS or ND4j (not single-threaded though I think) but they lack the important functionality described below.

Assuming I have a larger matrix and a smaller one I need to add the smaller one to the region of the larger one without the need to create an intermediary array or growing the smaller one to the size of the larger one with lots of zeros. In other words, I would like to get the functionality from the Breeze library from Scala - you create a view on the matrix which you then can use to do any operations like adding a sub-matrix.

Opened an [issue](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml/issues/61) in EJML.

Comment: I don't know scala, but isn't Scala library = JVM library?

Comment: Yes, but it's virtually impractical to use, as it heavily relies on implicit values which are missing in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that the best choice is [ojAlgo](https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo/wiki/Getting-Started). It has great performance according to this comprehensive [test](http://lessthanoptimal.github.io/Java-Matrix-Benchmark/runtime/2019_02_i53570/). What is important is that it allows very flexible transformations which can be executed in-place and lazily (many at once). For example

```
PrimitiveDenseStore m1 = PrimitiveDenseStore.FACTORY.makeZero(10, 10);
PrimitiveDenseStore m2 = PrimitiveDenseStore.FACTORY.makeZero(3, 3);

m2.add(0, 0, 5D);
m2.add(1, 1, 2D);
m2.add(1, 2, 3D);
m2.add(2, 1, -10D);

m1
    .regionByColumns(4, 5, 6)
    .regionByRows(4, 5, 6)
    .modifyMatching(PrimitiveMath.ADD, m2);

assertThat(m1.aggregateAll(MINIMUM)).isEqualTo(5);
```

More examples [here](https://www.ojalgo.org/code-examples/). Truly beautiful API and functionality.